# how can i add a menu link that goes to an external page

Tags: links, pages

i started a new blog and i see that there are two pages it starts out with:

1. Home
2. About

i want to add a third one but instead of having it load up an internal page, i want to have this go to an external link.  is this possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Admin Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus

If the theme is WP 3.0 ready, you will have an option to add a custom link (ie external link) on the left side, and you can drag and drop it into the order you want.

Justin Tadlock wrote an awesome post about 3.0 menus - http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus

If your theme isn't 3.0 ready, I believe you can still use the custom menu widget.

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, look under the pages. If not, somewhere else in the menu editor. Somewhere in there youve the possibility to enter an arbitrary URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your Theme is not 'Menu' ready, I suggest you to use my plugin 'Redirector' 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirector/
After activating the plugin you have a new meta box on the 'page' screen.
There you can select any of your pages or an external url